# Why can't I install greenlet (just a basic python package)?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I untarred it from: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet#downloads
(I'm in my virtual env. I sourced it, too, thats why I didn't sudo)

```
$ py setup.py  install
/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'repository'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing greenlet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to greenlet.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to greenlet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'greenlet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-i686/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'greenlet' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/greenlet.o
In file included from greenlet.c:5:
greenlet.h:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu you'd need to install the `python-dev` package. This provides the `Python.h` header:

```
% dpkg -S /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h
python2.6-dev: /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't have `python-dev` installed so there is no `Python.h` header.

Comment: I can't do "sudo aptitude install python-dev". Although it detects it and I type "Y" to install, it says that I get 404 errors when I try to install them.

Comment: that means you need to do "sudo aptitude update" first as the package list is out of date